# What is $\pi_3(SU(4)/SU(2))$?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

I want to know what is $\pi_3(SU(4)/SU(2))$ for the diagonal embedding of $SU(2)$ in $SU(4)$. People suggested this as a counterexample for [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460261/does-pi-1h-0-rightarrow-pi-3g-h-0-for-a-simple-and-simply-connected-lie) I asked on Math Overflow. Could someone provide the answer or references that teach how to compute it? Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unitary+group#InclusionOfUnitaryGroupnIntoUnitaryGroupnPlusIneIsnMinus1Equivalence)